# add element to array in powershell

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to add a Totals line to the array `$response_table`.
The line should be Totals = 56 (number), for example.
I've tried `$response_table += @{Name="Total"; Count=55};`, it adds a line with rubbish data.
Can you help with how to add this?
Code is below

```
[System.Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = [System.Net.SecurityProtocolType]::Tls12
$current_month = (Get-Date).month;
$current_year = (Get-Date).year;

$response_table=@();
$what_year=2019
$month_count=12
$current_month, $total_year, $current_date_interval;
$total_monthly=@(); # empty array, will be populated with values from the API
#$numbers += 5, 2, 3; # to add values to array

if ($what_year -eq $current_year)
{
    $month_count = $current_month-1;
}

for ($current_month=1; $current_month -le $month_count; $current_month++)
{
    $current_date_interval = -join($what_year, "-", $current_month);
    $uri="https://data.police.uk/api/crimes-street/bicycle-theft?poly=53.950624,-1.059234:53.951301,-1.049181:53.947361,-1.043420:53.950333,-1.030671:53.952997,-1.016427:53.950189,-1.013653:53.929487,-1.042286:53.942512,-1.054948:53.941936,-1.057172:53.944481,-1.060155s8&date="+$current_date_interval;
    $response = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $uri -Method Get -Headers $headers
    $response_table += $response | Group month |Select -Property name,count
    Write-Host $response_table;  
    $response | Group month |Select -Property name,count
    $total_year += $response.count;
}
Write-Host ($response_table|Measure-object -Property count -sum)
$response_table += @{Name="Total"; Count=55};
# does not work
$response_table | export-csv "list.csv" -notypeinformation
#add-content "list.csv" "Total,$total_year"
Write-Host "Yearly total"$total_year;
```

Comment: Maybe you should try `$response_table += [pscustomobject]@{Name="Total"; Count=55}` instead. So that you add a custom object with properties you have defined rather than just a hash table. There is likely a better way than all the uses of `+=`. That results in building the entire array every time and is inefficient.

Comment: @AdminOfThings The answer to your last point is to use `System.Collections.Generic.List[type]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [AdminOfThings](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11025476/adminofthings) indicates, **you're mistakenly adding a *hashtable* to the existing array of *custom objects*** (that `Select-Object` outputs).

**To construct a custom object in PSv3+, simply place `[pscustomobject]` before a hashtable literal**, which in your case means:

```
$response_table += [pscustomobject] @{Name="Total"; Count=55}
```

Now your `Export-Csv` command should work as intended.

As an aside: Up to PowerShell 6.x, `Export-Csv` only (meaningfully) supports *custom objects* as input, not also *hashtables*. v7 adds support for hashtables.

---

**Generally avoid using `+=` for appending to arrays:**

Arrays are fixed-size data structures, so what PowerShell must do when you "append to" an array with `+=` is to create a *new* array behind the scenes every time, which is quite inefficient in a loop.

While using an efficiently in-place extensible data structure such as `[System.Collections.ArrayList]` or `[System.Collections.Generic.List[object]]` is the next best thing, **the simplest and fastest approach is to simply let *PowerShell* collect multiple output objects in an array (`[object[]]`) for you, by assigning the entire loop as an expression to a variable**:

```
[array] $response_table = for ($current_month=1; $current_month -le $month_count; $current_month++)
  {
    $current_date_interval = -join($what_year, "-", $current_month);
    $uri="https://data.police.uk/api/crimes-street/bicycle-theft?poly=53.950624,-1.059234:53.951301,-1.049181:53.947361,-1.043420:53.950333,-1.030671:53.952997,-1.016427:53.950189,-1.013653:53.929487,-1.042286:53.942512,-1.054948:53.941936,-1.057172:53.944481,-1.060155s8&date="+$current_date_interval;
    $response = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $uri -Method Get -Headers $headers

    # *Output* the result of this pipeline, and PowerShell will
    # collect all outputs for you
    $response | Group month | Select -Property name,count

    $total_year += $response.count;
  }

# It's fine to use += to add the total, because you're only using it *once*.
$response_table += [pscustomobject] @{Name="Total"; Count=55}
```

<sup>Note: The `[array]` type constraint ensures that `$response_table` becomes an array even if the loop happens to have just *1* iteration.</sup>